# About Reductive Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

**Question**: Let $L$ be an reductive lie algebra,$H$ is an ideal of $L$.Let $S$ be the centralizer of $H$ in $L$, If $S$ is abelian, proof that $\left[ L,L\right]  \subseteq H$.

**My attempt**:Since $S$ be the centralizer of $H$ in $L$ and abelian, so it is solvable, it is easy to see that $Z\left( L\right)  \subseteq S$,but $L$ reductive, so $Rad\left( L\right)  =Z\left( L\right)  $,hence $Z\left( L\right)  =S$.I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know that $L \simeq [L,L] \oplus Z(L)$ and that $[L,L]$ is semisimple?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I know this, but I still don't know how to prove

Comment: Decompose $[L,L]$ into simple ideals $I_1 \oplus \dots \oplus I_n$. Assume for contradiction that some $I_k$ is not contained in $H$ i.e. $H\cap I_k = 0$. Then $I_k$ centralizes $H$.